# Entity Framework 6.2 Create index on Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, indexing

How do you set up Entity Framework clustered index and foreign keys?

```
public class WorkDay {
   public int Id { get;set;}
   public DateTime Date { get;set;}
   public Keyword Kw {get;set;}
}

public class Keyword {
   public int Id { get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to add index of Date and kw for the WorkDay entity, but cannot say how.

```
builder.Entity<WorkDay>().HasIndex(item => new { item.Date, item.Keyword });
```

this will give me error due to the fact that the mapping is only done for simple types

```
 builder.Entity<WorkDay>().HasIndex(item => new { item.Date, item.Keyword.Id });
```

gives me error

```
The properties expression 'item => new <>f__AnonymousType21`2(Date = item.Date, Id = item.Keyword.Id)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the foreign key (e.g. WorkDay.KeywordId) and reference that when defining the index.

Comment: Is that the only way? Feels like it is taking a step back when having to have both an fk property and the navigation property?

Comment: EFCore has a HasIndex overload that accepts strings for field names, not sure if EF6 has that support.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasindex?view=efcore-2.1